# How do the elements of the product-$\sigma$-algebra look like?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ and let $\mathcal{E}$ denote he product-$\sigma$-algebra on $X$, where the set $\left\{0,1,2\right\}$ is equipped with the power set as $\sigma$-algebra.

It is known that the set $\mathcal{C}$ containing all cylinder sets
$$
C_t[a_0,...,a_m]:=\left\{x=(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\in X: x_t=a_0,x_{t+1}=a_1,...,x_{t+m}=a_m\right\}, 
$$
where $a_i\in\left\{0,1,2\right\}\forall 0\leqslant i\leqslant m$,
generates $\mathcal{E}$, i.e. $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{E}$.

---

Maybe this is a stupid question, but how do the elements of $\mathcal{E}$ look like? Surely, the cylinder sets are in $\mathcal{E}$, okay. But how do the other elements of $\mathcal{E}$ look like? Or maybe it is not possible to say?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable,  you can also conclude that for any family $\{E_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}$,  $\prod_{i\in \mathbb{Z}} E_i$ is in $\mathcal{E}$.